# Can I override values in external PropertySource over the application specific profile properties

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, config

I have an external properties file that is present in Hashicorp and am pulling it to Spring Boot using `@PropertySource` annotation.
In my Spring Boot application, there are profile specific `application.properties` files.
Now what I want is the `PropertySource` config to take precedence over these profile specific config.

I read through the Spring Boot External Config doc already- https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.1.13.RELEASE/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html which mentions `PropertySource` config is least preference

```
@PropertySource(value="${path}",ignoreResourceNotFound = true)
public class MyApplication {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(MyApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

In my application.properties file-

```
name=value
```

In my external config file-

```
name=updatedNewValue
```

What I want is to retrieve the the 'updatedNewValue', instead I get 'value'.

Is it possible to override it?

Answer (score 0):

Specific profiles take precedence over the default profile. You can have placename=value in your file.properties (or properties.yml) and a second file named file-.properties (test, prod, stage are common options) with the placeholder placename=value.

[Remember to provide the profile the application as configuration before running it.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aZ5Fz.png)

Comment: But I want is to override profile specific properties with external config file specified by @PropertySource annotation.

Comment: Does it make any difference the way you override it? what about multiple property sources?

@PropertySources({
    @PropertySource("classpath:application.properties"),
    @PropertySource(")
})

Answer (score 0):

If you want to overwrite a property for a specific profile, using an external configuration, your external file/source must be profile specific:
`properties-profile.properties` (if it's file-based)

You mentioned Hashicorp... Not sure if it's Vault or Consul, but for Vault, you can define a profile-specific value using:

`vault write secret/application,profile foo=bar`